# Cordova cordova-plugin-websql plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins, windows-runtime, windows-10

I have Cordova app which runs on android and ios and WinRt 8.1 with **cordova-plugin-websql** plugin, but when I run it on windows 10 I am getting this exception:

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Connection is not set

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but if I'm using this plugin from GitHub it works both on 8.1 and on 10 Windows.
link:
https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-websql